# Entity Framework 4.3 Migration Strategy for Database Used by Multiple Applications

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I've been working on an ASP.NET Entity Framework 4.3 Code-First application, which governs the model for the parts of the database it cares about. As this database will be used by multiple other applications (some not using ef so can't import models) the idea was to create the base database with my application. After this the DBA could add other fields and tables not used by my application as necessary.

The problem arrises when implementing changes to the model in my application. Our idea was to use the new Migrations feature of EF 4.3 to create scripts (-script feature) while pointing to our local machine dev db (SQLCompact), which will then be passed to the DBA for migrating the actual dev database (MS SQL 2008) that all of the other applications use.

This has been causing problems though, as when I began testing (pointing to SQL server) the application couldn't read any foreign key relationships, giving errors that these columns don't exist. I'm wondering if this is caused by the differences in translation of SQL Compact and SQL Server (EF to SQL), or some other problem is the cause.

Should I be bothering with EF migrations for this type of 1-DB multiple App environment at all? Do I need to run all my migrations directly against the SQL Server? Is there an entirely different change strategy I should be using? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try installing SQL Server Express locally instead of using compact.  That should get rid of any differences there might be between compact and standard.

Comment: Setting that up at the moment, that should hopefully solve issues with different SQL commands or naming convention translations. Do you think that this is the right way to go for change management though?

Comment: Realised that different SQL version isn't the problem except for some small type changes, and that wouldn't be solved by SQL Express anyway.